# Inverse limit of groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Can we replace topological spaces by groups in Corollary 1.1.6 from the [this link](http://www.springer.com/cda/content/document/cda_downloaddocument/9783642016417-c1.pdf?SGWID=0-0-45-865655-p173989968)?

In other words, does the following theorem is true?

Let $Y$ is the inverse limit of system of groups $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^r$ and morphisms $\{f_j\}_{j\in J}$. Assume we have a group $X$ and surjective morphisms $\phi _:X\to X_i$ which are competable with the morphisms $\{f_j\}_{j\in J}$ then the natural group morphism $\psi :X\to Y$ is also surjective.

Clarification: my question refer only to finite number of groups in the diagram, in particular the $p$-adic are not counter example.

Comment: I'd be surprised if the link you posted worked on any machine other than yours!

Comment: Sorry, the link was replaced.

Comment: I didn't know if I can answer my own question so I put it as comment. The answer to the above question is no. Take the following groups, $G=C_2=\langle x \rangle$, $H=C_2=\langle y \rangle$ and consider trivial morphisms from $G,H$ to the trivial group. The inverse limit of this diagram is $C_2\times C_2$. However, there is an onto morphism from the group $G=C_2=\langle z \rangle$ which make the diagram commutative.